# Como hago un codigo que reinicie una linea del output cuando esta ocupada por un print

Tags: python

Digamos: tengo un código con pygame

```
print(pygame.mouse.pos) #se iprime un nuevo texto cada vez que la posicion de lursor dentro de la ventana cambie
```

necesito saber como hago para hacer que el texto se imprima en un solo lugar

30, 50, luego en su lugar sale 31,49, etc
sientanse libres de pedir mas detalles

en vez de

```
hola
hola
hola
hola
```

quiero que hola se actualize en la mima linea del output

```
hola #esto sale varias veces en el mismo lugar
```

Comment: Hola Gabriel no termino de entender a que te refieres con "que el texto se imprima en un solo lugar" ¿Quieres que el print solo se produzca cuando el cursor esté en una posición concreta y no cada vez que se mueva el cursor?  Por cierto, ¿Dónde tienes localizada esta línea? Por otro lado el título también  es un poco confuso "reinicie una linea del output cuando esta ocupada por un print".... Intenta explicar con algo más de detalle cual es exactamente el comportamiento esperado.

Comment: así quiero que luzca el output:

Comment: hola #que se impria varias veces en la misma linea, limpiandola

Comment: en vez de esto:

Comment: hola                                                                                                                          hola                                                                                                                      hola                       así no es como yo quiero que luzca

Comment: Vale creo que lo entiendo ¿Tienes más prints concurrentes? Esto complicaría la cosa bastante si usar  `os.system("clear")` no es una opción... Dado que usas interfaces gráficas, ene este último caso sería mejor prescindir de mostrar datos por la terminal y hacerlo por la interfaz.

Comment: gracias te lo agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ese `print()` es el único que tienes (o el que sale en la última línea de la terminal) una forma sencilla de lograr lo que buscas sería retroceder el cursor al principio de la línea antes de imprimir. De ese modo lo que imprimas sobreescribirá a lo que había.

Para retroceder el cursor al inicio de una línea el carácter a enviar a la terminal es `\r`. A la vez debes asegurarte de que Python no envía un carácter "nueva línea", para lo que debes usar el parámetro extra `end=""` en el `print()` (Python3) o una coma al final de `print` (Python2).

Por ejemplo (python3):

```py
import time

for i in range(10,0,-1):
   print("\rCuenta atrás: {}      ".format(i), end="")
   time.sleep(1)
print("\nDespegue!")
```